# Exclude directory from WordPress htaccess AND redirect old .html files

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a WordPress install which is replacing an old website. The old (Movable Type) website had `.html` files which I want to redirect to their new equivalents. This works to redirect `/foo.html` to `/foo/`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

BUT I *also* want to exclude a few other directories, that contain old `.html` files from WordPress - so that they can still be accessed as before. I've seen from other answers that I can add the line marked below to WordPress's `.htaccess` statements to exclude a directory from its rewriting:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# NEW LINE:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(mydirectory|mydirectory/.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have two questions:

1. If I comment out that first block, that new line still doesn't let me access, say `/mydirectory/foo.html` - WP redirects to `/missing/`. I can't work out why.
2. I'm not sure how to combine these two sets of rules. ie, Anything in `/mydirectory/` is accessed as before, but all other URLs ending in `.html` should be rewritten to `/filename/`, and WP's other stuff works as normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# NEW RULE to ignore rewriting for anything in mydirectory
RewriteRule ^mydirectory(/.*)?$ - [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ /$1/ [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava, that seems to do the trick! I'd never have got there on my own.